# How do I enable an autoresponder on a group using a headless script?

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

When my support staff home they have to enable the auto responder every single day. I want to automate this. I'm really not picky as to how to do this. The scripts interface doesn't seem to allow this and the restful API seems to only work interactively and not on a group. Any advice as to where to start?